# Ubuntu image for Pine64

Tags: ubuntu-core

Where could I get an Ubuntu image for the Pine64?  In the download page of the Ubuntu website, there are a number of variants of images from raspbery Pi to Intel NUC, etc.  But I could not find any specifically for the Pine64 board?  Does anyone know where I could download this image, if it exists?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Ubuntu 19.10 has [**.dtb* files](http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/eoan/main/installer-arm64/current/images/device-tree/) to support the Pine64 board. So you can try to download arm64 [netboot image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/19.10/) and start over it. Or try [*ubuntu-19.10-server-arm64.iso*](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/ubuntu-19.10-server-arm64.iso) image.

Or use one of alternative [Armbian images](https://www.armbian.com/pine64/).